# How to divide launching tests for different bit of Windows

Tags: webdriver, selenium-grid

I've got task for launch test for web on Windows x64 and Windows x86. 
I've set up Selenium Grid (1 Hub and two Nodes). 
How can i launch tests for Win x64 only?

I didnt find parameter for x64 or x86 when i launch selenium server on Node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using different platform values

```
java -jar selenium.jar -role node -hub http://yourhubaddress:hubport/grid/register -browser browserName=iexplorer,platform=win7
```

For x86

```
java -jar selenium.jar -role node -hub http://yourhubaddress:hubport/grid/register -browser browserName=iexplorer,platform=XP
```

Now, in your test you just need to set the correct browserName. Something like

```
DesiredCapabilities customIECapability=DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
if(propertywhichcontainsbrowseryouwanttorun=x64IE){
customIECapability.setPlatform("win7");
}
else
if(propertywhichcontainsbrowseryouwanttorun="x32IE"){
customIECapability.setPlatform("XP");
}
WebDriver driver = new RemoteDriver("huburl",customIECapability);
```

This should redirect your tests to appropriate machines.